# How to set default value in input datalist and still have the drop down?

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the `datalist` HTML property to get a drop down inout box:

```html
<input list="orderTypes" value="Book">
<datalist id="orderTypes">
  <option value="Book">
  <option value="Copy">
  <option value="Page">
</datalist>
```

The problem is that now I have to clear the input box to view all the drop down values. Is there a way to have a default value but still view all the values in the datalist when the drop down icon is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know of no way to do this natively. You could make a "helper" div to use when the input field has value. I couldn't hide the native drop down so I renamed the ID. Uses jQuery.

html

```
<input list="orderTypes" id="dlInput">
<div id="helper" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:200;border:1pt solid #ccc;"></div>
<datalist id="orderTypes" style="z-index:100;">
   <option value="Book">
   <option value="Copy">    
   <option value="Page">
</datalist>
```

script

```
$(function(){
    // make a copy of datalist 
    var dl="";
    $("#orderTypes option").each(function(){
            dl+="<div class='dlOption'>"+$(this).val()+"</div>";
    });
    $("#helper").html(dl);
    $("#helper").width( $("#dlInput").width() );

    $(document).on("click","#dlInput",function(){
        // display list if it has value
        var lv=$("#dlInput").val();
        if( lv.length ){
                $("#orderTypes").attr("id","orderTypesHide");
                $("#helper").show();
        }
    });

    $(document).on("click",".dlOption",function(){
        $("#dlInput").val( $(this).html() );
        $("#helper").hide();
    });

    $(document).on("change","#dlInput",function(){
        if( $(this).val()==="" ){
            $("#orderTypesHide").attr("id","orderTypes");
            $("#helper").hide();
        }
    }); 
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shawnsBrain66/c8m94L2k/1/)

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem.
I just simple added placeholder with the default data.
In your example:

```html
<input list="orderTypes" name="orderType" id="orderType" placeholder="Book" />
```

I listen submit event. If the input value is empty, I use `Book` as default value, otherwise I use the given value...

```js
$("#mySubmitButton").click(() => {
    // use event prevent here if need...
    const orderType = $("#orderType").val() || "Book";
    console.log(orderType);
});
```

Comment: well this works for me .. thank you

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you trying to do?

```js
    var demoInput = document.getElementById('demoInput'); // give an id to your input and set it as variable
    demoInput.value ='books'; // set default value instead of html attribute
    demoInput.onfocus = function() { demoInput.value =''; }; // on focus - clear input
    demoInput.onblur = function() { demoInput.value ='books'; }; // on leave restore it.
```

```html
<legend>(double) click on the input to see options:</legend>
    <input list="orderTypes" id="demoInput">
    <datalist id="orderTypes">
      <option value="Book">
      <option value="Copy">
      <option value="Page">
    </datalist>
```

The only "problem" here is that in order to see the options the user have to click the input again so it's like "double-click the input to see options".

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `input`'s `placeholder` attribute along with a Javascript code that'll make sure that the field isn't empty upon submission.

Obviously this is just an example, you'll have to modify the submission event.

```js
document.getElementById('submitButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
  let inputElement = document.getElementById('myInput');
  if (!inputElement.value) {
    inputElement.value = 'Book';
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="myInput" list="orderTypes" placeholder="Book">
<datalist id="orderTypes">
  <option value="Book">
  <option value="Copy">
  <option value="Page">
</datalist>
<input id="submitButton" type="submit">
```

Comment: And css the ::placeholder like other input text color

Answer (score 0):

I've menaged to get what You described with just `<select>` + `<option>` tags instead of `<input>` + `<datalist>`:

```
<select name="sortBY">

  <option value="Book">Book</option>
  <option value="Copy">Copy</option>
  <option value="Page">Page</option>
</select>
```

Putting it all inside `<form></form>` tags will send it eg. with POST method with `$_POST['sortBY']` value.

Answer (score 0):

If this helps at all:

`$('#grouptext').val($('#grouplist option#48').attr('value'));`

where '#grouptext' is your text input to which your datalist '#grouplist' is attached, and #48 is the ID you're looking to "pre-select".

here's what my data list looks like, for clarity
[image: here's what my data list looks like, for clarity...]

worked for me.

In Chrome's console it shows up like this with "option#115", which corresponds to the correct text in the datalist for that "id" (being 115)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
//In case anyone finds it helpful (using jquery):
 <input type="text" list="listmiscomis" id="pon"/>
        <datalist id="listmiscomis">
            <option value="uno">uno</option>
            <option value="dos">dos</option>
            <option value="tres">tres</option>
            <option value="cuatro">cuatro</option>
            <option value="cinco">cinco</option>
        </datalist>   
//mark option
  $('#pon').val("dos");    
//having the focus passes the value to the place holder
$("#pon").on("focus",function(){
        if($('#pon').val() !== ""){
        let cont = $('#pon').val();
        $('#pon').attr("placeholder",cont);
        $('#pon').val("");
}
})    
//when it loses focus and if no option was selected it passes the place holder as value
$("#pon").blur(function(){
        if($('#pon').val() == ""){
        let valor = $('#pon').attr("placeholder");
        $('#pon').val(valor);
        $('#pon').removeAttr("placeholder");
    }
})
remove focus when selecting option
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#pon").change(function(){
        $("#pon").blur();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<form action="index.html" method="get">
            <label for="browser">Choose your browser from the list:</label>
            <input list="browsers" name="browser" id="browser" placeholder="Select an option">
            <datalist id="browsers">
                <option value="Edge">
                <option value="Firefox">
                <option value="Chrome">
                <option value="Opera">
                <option value="Safari">
            </datalist>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

set id for your input and with js set default value

```
<script>
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById('orderTypes').value = "Book";
    }, 100);
</script>
```

Comment: Using setTimeout here is unnecessary and suboptimal. Check some of the other answers on the page for more effective solutions.

Comment: for sole reason if I don't use set time out, it doesn't works. I think library needs load first