# Datalist displays duplicate (redundant) suggestions

Tags: html, html-datalist

I have a html table which contains multiple input fields in order to process some data about an entry. One input contains the code, the user can manually modify the predefined code (if any) and add a custom id. this is how I implemented the input field described above

```
<input id="productCode_99999908" class="form-control id-control" list="productList_99999908" value="99999908">
<datalist id="productList_99999908">
... options
</datalist>
```

The options look like these (I do not have duplicated options):

```
....
                       <option value="45577">
                            45577
                        </option>
                        <option value="300046592">
                            300046592
                        </option>
                        <option value="300005449">
                            300005449
                        </option>
                        <option value="300013358">
                            300013358
                        </option>
                        <option value="300015407">
                            300015407
                        </option>
                        <option value="300020294">
                            300020294
                        </option>
...
```

The problem arises after I modify the predefined id with a custom one. It displays 2 times as a suggestion the custom id (the custom id exists in the system, I say custom because it was manually written by the user) and it looks like this:

[image]

With the predefined ids it looks like this

[image]

It doesn't even display a single option, even though the option with that id is present in the datalist.

I have tried to turn off autocomplete and checked for duplicated options, but none of these worked. What am I doing wrong? Why do I get these suggestions displayed twice when an user changes the predefined id with one already existent in the system?

*Snippet example:*

```html
<input id="productCode_99999908" class="form-control id-control" list="productList_99999908" value="99999908" >
<datalist id="productList_99999908">
  <option value="45577">
    45577
  </option>
  <option value="300046592">
    300046592
  </option>
  <option value="300005449">
    300005449
  </option>
  <option value="300013358">
    300013358
  </option>
  <option value="300015407">
    300015407
  </option>
  <option value="300020294">
    300020294
  </option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: Putting your code in a snippet doesn't show this error. With the details you've given, it's not reproducible. You've probably got some JS somewhere which is messing with your input.

Comment: @Joundill The `value` attribute was missing to the input in the snippet above, indeed is very weird. But if you take a look, with the predefined id, when you click to edit it, you get no suggestions. If you put `300005449` and then click to edit it you get suggestions. Why?

Comment: Have a read of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977572/how-to-set-default-value-in-input-datalist-and-still-have-the-drop-down/56977926)